# Souffle query returning zero results

Tags: database, datalog

I am writing a [Souffle](https://souffle-lang.github.io/) query that operates on family relationships:

```
.decl Parent(x: symbol, y: symbol)
.input Parent

.decl Descendant(x: symbol, y: symbol)
.output Descendant
.printsize Descendant

Descendant(x, y) :- Parent(x, y).
Descendant(x, y) :- Parent(z, y), Descendant(x, z).

.decl Qslow(x: symbol)
.output Qslow
.printsize Qslow

Qslow(x) :- Descendant("Alice", x).
```

I have some facts in a TSV file `Parent.facts`:

```
"Alice" "john"
"john"  "mary"
"mary"  "elizabeth"
"Bob"   "charles"
```

And running `souffle` seems to generate the right output for the `Descendant` relation (three descendants for "Alice"):

```
hickory% souffle -F. -D. descendants.dl
Descendant      7
Qslow   0
hickory%
```

However, `Qslow` produces **zero** results. I would instead expect **three** results. This makes me suspicious of the definition of `Qslow`, but I am not sure what the issue is. Am I doing something weird with symbol syntax? It looks like I am using the same syntax as [in the docs](https://souffle-lang.github.io/types#float-type).

If I try adding another clause to the conjunction, I still get zero results:

```
Qslow(x) :- Descendant(y, x), y="Alice".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified the file `Parent.facts` in the wrong data format. It should be

```
john    mary
mary    elizabeth
Bob charles
```

without double quotes and tabs to separate elements of tuples. Only facts in the program use double-quotes.

Comment: This is it! Thank you. I had the tabs, and I could have sworn I had tried without quotes, but only now it works. Super.